# VBA Code to Print Multiple Sheet using the VBA Worksheet name and Visible

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working code to Print Multiple worksheet Using the VBA worksheet with the condition of Visible=True and excluding specific worksheet.  I am not getting anywhere.

```
Sub Printetail()
'
' PrintDetail Macro
'
    Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
    If Not wsSheet Is Nothing Then

      If wsSheet.Visible = True 
         And wsSheet.CodeName <> "EstimateBasis" 
         And wsSheet.CodeName <> "CashFlow" 
         And wsSheet.CodeName <> "MaterialPVTable" 
         And wsSheet.CodeName <> "Material" 
         And wsSheet.CodeName <> "Instruction"
         And wsSheet.CodeName <> "DebugSheet"
         And wsSheet.CodeName <> "StateLocalTax" 
         And wsSheet.CodeName <> "Referene" 
      Then
          '???
      End If

      If wsSheet.CodeName = "ProjectInput" Then

          wsSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter = ActiveSheet.Range("C6").Text & _
                                           "    -Estimate Date:" & _
                                           ActiveSheet.Range("F2").Text & _
                                           "    -Gate:" & _
                                           ActiveSheet.Range("F4").Text & _
                                           "    -Rev No." & _
                                           ActiveSheet.Range("F5").Text

          wsSheet.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False

      Else

          wsSheet.Visible = True
          wsSheet.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False

      End If

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`wsSheet` is `Nothing` because you haven't assigned it anywere. You'll want to iterate worksheets of `ThisWorkbook` instead; something like this should get you somewhere:

```
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
For Each wsSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If CanPrintThisSheet(wsSheet) Then PrintWorksheet wsSheet

Next
```

And then `CanPrintThisSheet` would be a `Boolean`-returning function where you'd put all the conditionals for "can print a sheet" and `PrintWorksheet` would be a sub/procedure where you'd put the page setup and printing logic (which *can* be nothing more than a call to `ws.PrintOut`):

```
Function CanPrintThisSheet(sheet As Worksheet) As Boolean
    CanPrintThisSheet = sheet.Visible And Not StringMatchesAny(sheet.CodeName, _
             "EstimateBasis", _
             "CashFlow", _
             "MaterialPVTable", _
             "Material", _
             "Instruction", _
             "DebugSheet", _
             "StateLocalTax", _
             "Referene")
End Function
```

Using a function like "StringMatchesAny" below, avoids having to perform *all* checks, since the function returns as soon as a match is found:

```
Function StringMatchesAny(string_source, ParamArray find_strings()) As Boolean

    'String-typed local copies of passed parameter values:
    Dim find As String, src As String, i As Integer, found As Boolean
    src = CStr(string_source)

    For i = LBound(find_strings) To UBound(find_strings)
        find = CStr(find_strings(i))
        found = (src = find)
        If found Then Exit For
    Next

    StringMatchesAny = found

End Function
```

Comment: I am little confuse. In the Funtion CanPrintThisSheet = Not StringMatchesAny( do I need to list all the sheet name? I am using the VB Sheet code name because this sheet will be rename. I have a total of 72 sheet and I only want to print the only ones that are visible with the exception of 5 sheets

Comment: I've edited the function to better reflect your intent - the idea is to make it return `False` when the sheet is not visible or when its `CodeName` matches any of the 5 sheet codenames you want to skip. But your biggest problem is the first `If` which always evaluates to `True`, so start by setting up a loop to iterate the worksheets in the workbook and then you'll have a `wsSheet` that's not `Nothing` for every iteration; then verify if you want to print that sheet (`CanPrintThisSheet`) and if so, set it up for printing and print it (`PrintWorksheet`).

Comment: Thank you so much ReatilCoder!  It is nice to find people that like to share their knowledge.  I am so into this that I am planning to take a class.

Comment: Hello retailcoder.  I am still unable to create this code. :-( I tried but not success.  what i am confused is this portion: StringMatchesAny(sheet.CodeName, _
             "no-print-sheet-name1", _
             "no-print-sheet-name2", _
             "no-print-sheet-name3", _
             "...")
I have a total of 72 sheets, the all may or may not get used.  65 of them are hidden and the will be unhidin when the sheet is needed. So Do I have to list all 65 sheet code name in this section

Comment: @user2403046 It's based on the code you posted, I've edited my answer to better show what it stands for. You don't *need* to enumerate sheet code names, all you need is to put a condition inside `CanPrintThisSheet` that returns `True` when a sheet can be printed, whatever that condition is: if you want to skip hidden sheets, make it return `False` if the sheet isn't visible. If you want to skip specific sheet names (as your OP was hinting), then make it return `False` if the sheet's code name matches any of the names you want to skip.

Comment: So Do I have to list all 65 sheets code name in this section? Sub PrintDetail() ‘ PrintDeatil Macro ‘Dim wsSheet As Worksheet For Each wsSheet in This Workbook.Worksheets If CanPrintThisSheet(wsSheet) Then PrintWorksheet wsSheet Next Funtion CanPrintThisSheet(sheet As Worksheet) As Boolean CanPrintThisSheet = Sheet.Visible And Not StringMatchesAny(Sheet.Codename=PipeDetail1, Sheet.Codename=PipeDetail2, Sheet.Codename=PipeDetail3…etc will alother 65 sheets, plus the “no-print-sheet-name, plus sheets I don’t want to print.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. only the the one I don't have to print. like this Sub Printdetail()
'
' PrintDetail Macro
'
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
For Each wsSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If CanPrintThisSheet(wsSheet) Then PrintWorksheet wsSheet
    
Next
    Function CanPrintThisSheet(sheet As Worksheet) As Boolean
     CanPrintThisSheet = sheet.Visible And Not StringMatchesAny(sheet.CodeName, "EstimateBasis", "CashFlow", "MaterialPVTable", "Material", "Instruction", "DebugSheet", "StateLocalTax", "Referene")

End Function

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to accept this answer if it helped you resolve your issue :)